# PhpStorm Xdebug multiple users same session remotely on Ubuntu

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

The problem is the Session ID. It seems like its the same on for all users.
We use the Xdebug browser extension and listen in PhpStorm for incoming connections. No other settings.

Comment: What does session ID have to do with Xdebug? You also have settings for Xdebug 2 and Xdebug 3, which one you using?

Comment: The `idekey` is only relevant with DBGp proxies, too.

Comment: So it should be possible that we all work with phpstrom and debug? The Version is  Xdebug v3.1.2

Comment: There are two ways multiple developers can debug on the same server simultaneously. One is `xdebug.discover_client_host`, Xdebug will send the debug data to the machine where the HTTP request came from. Note that it only works if the server and the development machines are on the same LAN, meaning that the server should be able to initiate a TCP connection to the IP the HTTP request came from. Another option is the DBGp proxy, check [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010264920-xdebug-multiple-developers-php-storm-dbgpproxy).

Comment: @EugeneMorozov There are three, as there is also Xdebug Cloud, which avoid some of the connectivity issues.